# Is there a better way to catch both errors AND completions?

Tags: reactive-cocoa

Currently I create an inner signal to call `[Watchtower reportToServerWithBeaconRegionArraySignal:]`, because that way I can only pass the `next`s on, and catch completion and error signals, which I don't want to propagate because I want to stay subscribed for further signals from `[self rangedBeaconsSignal]`.

I'm sure there must be a better way, but I can't see it: I've tried using `catch:` (and returning `[RACSignal empty]` from the provided block there), but that only catches errors, not completions.

(p.s. can I just check my use of `[disposable dispose]` is also correct here? possibly it's redundant):

```
[[[self rangedBeaconsSignal] flattenMap:^RACStream * (CLBeaconRegion *region) {

        return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable * (id <RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
            RACDisposable *disposable= [RACDisposable new];
            [[Watchtower reportToServerWithBeaconRegionArraySignal:@[region] fromBackground:NO]
                subscribeNext:^(id x) {
                    [subscriber sendNext:x];
                } error:^(NSError *error) {
                    [disposable dispose];
                } completed:^{
                    [disposable dispose];
                }];
            return disposable;
        }];

    }] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(@"Sent beacon to server");
     } error:^(NSError *error) {
        // ideally errors might reach here, but I don't want to unsubscribe, so I'm ignoring them for now. 
     } completed:^{
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer I think, this works for me. Basically the `completed` is caught and ignored, the error is based to the subscriber and then caught using a `catch:` (returning empty), and then it's wrapped in a `-repeat` statement so that it doesn't give up for the next rangedBeacon. woo!

```
[[[[[self rangedBeaconsSignal]
        flattenMap:^RACStream * (CLBeaconRegion *region) {
            return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable * (id <RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
                RACDisposable *disposable = [RACDisposable new];

                [[Watchtower reportToServerWithBeaconRegionArraySignal:@[ region ] fromBackground:NO]
                    subscribeNext:^(id x) {
                        [subscriber sendNext:x];
                    } error:^(NSError *error) {
                        [subscriber sendError:error];
                    } completed:^{
                        [disposable dispose];
                    }
                ];

                return disposable;
            }];
        }]
        catch:^RACSignal * (NSError *error) {
            NSLog (@"Caught server error..");
            return [RACSignal empty];
        }]
        repeat] // means that it'll keep trying for the next ranged regions
        subscribeNext:^(id x) {
            NSLog(@"Sent beacon to server");
        }];
```